# how to combine multiline docker log into one fluentd event

Tags: docker, fluentd

Hope someone could help me because this problem has confused me for several days...

I'm using fluentd to centralize docker container's logs. so I set docker run options:

```
log-driver=fluentd
log-opt=fluentd-address=fluentd.marathon.mesos:24224
log-opt=tag=server
log-opt=fluentd-async-connect=true
```

and received json objects like

```
{container_id:xxx, container_name:xxx, log:xxx, ...}
```

for example a java exception stack trace will be like this:

```
{log:exampleException:error, ...}
{log:\tat java.xxx, ...}
{log:\tat java.xxx, ...}
```

Now my question is: how can I combine them together? Like multline in logstash.

The correct answer I'm expecting is:

```
{log:exampleException:error\n\tat java.xxx\n\tat java.xxx, ...}
```

My fluentd input is in_forward not in_tail, so from the document I can't use the multiline plugin built in fluentd core.

Then I found this plugin https://github.com/quick-sort/fluent-plugin-multiline-parser

But because my log received from docker doesn't contain '\n' at the end of each line, this plugin combined all my log into only one line!

e.g. I use the word "Exception" to mark the firstline, but the answer I get is:

```
{log:Exception:error\tat java.xxx\tat java.xxx, ...}
```

It treated my docker log as a single line and seperated them by word "Exception"

I have tried to add a '/n' to every log by filter record_transformer, but the filter changed my '\n' into '\\n'automatically, so it also fails

I also find a plugin https://github.com/okkez/fluent-plugin-concat but have problem installing this plugin

Recently I haven't found any method

Answer (score 1):

My answer is installing the multiline-parser plugin and enable ruby to add the '\n'

```
<filter server.**>
  type record_transformer
  enable_ruby
  <record>
    log ${record["log"]+"\n"}
  </record>
</filter>
```